# How to perform mouse click action when looping

Tags: c#

I need to make some automatic clicks in certain positions, but when I put the method inside the FOR the click action is only executed in the last loop.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, uint dwExtraInfo);
//Mouse actions
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;
public void DoMouseClick()
{
    // Call the imported function with the cursor's current position
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);

public static void MoveCursorToPoint(int x, int y)
{
    SetCursorPos(x, y);
}
```

How I wish to use:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
    MoveCursorToPoint(100, 100);
    DoMouseClick();
}
```

The click action works perfectly, however when I put in some loop the program only clicks when it is in the last loop.

How to do the click action whenever it is requested inside the looping?

Comment: Try with a small delay `Thread.Sleep(250)` at the bottom of the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be happening too fast. Try adding a small delay after the click event to allow the OS to have time to process it before firing more.